# Adding a record with a stored procedure does not quite work

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I'm experiencing some issues with adding a record in a ms sql server database with an access form. I enter data in my access form, then I execute a stored procedure which should add the data to 2 different tables.

The issue here is, the data is being submitted to one table, but not in the other one. Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddArticle]
( 
   @description VARCHAR(128),
   @stock integer,
   @price decimal(8,2),
   @startdate varchar(30),
   @enddate varchar(30),
   @supplier varchar(128)
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
IF (
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM article  
   WHERE description = @description
   ) = 0 
   begin try
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @articlenr INT
        SELECT @articlenr = MAX(articlenr) + 1 FROM article

        INSERT INTO article (articlenr, description, catcode, supplier, stock) 
         VALUES (@articlenr, @description, NULL, @supplier, @stock)

        INSERT INTO articleprice (articlenr, price, startdate, enddate) 
        VALUES (@articlenr, @price, @startdate, @enddate)
    commit
    Raiserror('The article has been added!', 16, 1)

  end try

   begin catch
       if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       begin
                  ROLLBACK
       end
       Raiserror('An article with description %s already exists!', 16,1,@description)

   end catch
END
```

The data is being added to table article, but not to articleprice, and I just can't seem to figure out why... Any idea's?

Hope you guys can help me out here..

Answer (score 1):

The are a number of issues with this stored procedure.  I can't explain why the second insert is failing but the error handling will obfuscate errors.  The "success" raiseerror will fire the catch block due to the severity 16 error.  A more serious issue is that the code is vulnerable to race conditions (both the `EXISTS` check and the `SELECT MAX`).  I added an `UPDLOCK` hint to serialize for the purpose of this proc.  The version below requires SQL 2012 or later.  If you are using an earlier version, change the `CATCH` block handling to use `RAISERROR` instead of `THROW`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddArticle]
( 
   @description VARCHAR(128),
   @stock integer,
   @price decimal(8,2),
   @startdate varchar(30),
   @enddate varchar(30),
   @supplier varchar(128)
) 
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON; --rowcount messages can confuse some applications, especially ADO classic API

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT *
       FROM article  WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) --serialize access for this proc
       WHERE description = 'a'
       )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @articlenr INT;

        SELECT @articlenr = MAX(articlenr) + 1 FROM article;

        INSERT INTO article (articlenr, description, catcode, supplier, stock) SELECT @articlenr, @description, NULL, @supplier, @stock);

        INSERT INTO articleprice (articlenr, price, startdate, enddate) VALUES (@articlenr, @price, @startdate, @enddate);

        COMMIT;

        RAISERROR('The article has been added!', 0, 0); --informational message for debugging

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR('An article with description %s already exists!', 16,1,@description);

    END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    THROW;
END CATCH
GO
```